# What does -fheinous-gnu-extensions option do?

Tags: clang

When Homebrew compiles libgcrypt on OS X, it patches it to use clang and add `-std=gnu89` and `-fheinous-gnu-extensions` to the `CFLAG` Makefile var. What does the latter do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/SemaStmtAsm_8cpp.html](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/SemaStmtAsm_8cpp.html#a452b11e074d284c7a1140521e81df7c7) says:

> GNU C has an extremely ugly extension whereby they silently ignore "noop" casts in places where an lvalue is required by an inline asm. We emulate this behavior when -fheinous-gnu-extensions is specified, but provide a strong guidance to not use it.

No, I haven’t used it; I don’t know why Homebrew needed it.

Comment: I wonder where this practice of highly opinionated option naming is going. When are we going to be forced to specify `-fby-using-this-option-you-surrender-your-soul-to-the-devil-and-will-burn-in-hell`?

Comment: They may be indicating that the feature is likely to cause bugs, and that the user should be afraid of it for this reason.